# GraphQL: Cannot return null for non-nullable field

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, prisma

I'd created gql `fragment` as below without `photo` part at first.
And then later I added **photo {id}** part on this fragment.

```
export const COMMENT_FRAGMENT = gql`
  fragment CommentFragment on Comment {
    id
    user {
      username
      avatar
    }
    payload
    isMine
    createdAt

    photo {
      id
    }

  }
`;
```

But it shows **error** message:

```
    "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Comment.photo.",
    "path": Array [
      "seeFeed",
      1,
      "comments",
      0,
      "photo",
    ],
  },
```

Strange thing is I checked several times that there's no null or empty field of photo.id of comments.

[image]

As you can see, Comment field has photo[] and photo has 'id', which means my fragment has no error.

When I searched about it people say it is not my query problem, but something about migration?

Can you help me? :(